# UIDatePicker keyboard-like interface

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

I launch a keyboard-like interface for `UIDatePicker` using this code:

```
    _meetingtimeTF.delegate = self;
datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
[datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime];
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(onDatePickerValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
_meetingtimeTF.inputView = datePicker;
```

1. Is there a way to customize the size? Currently the white panel take up the whole horizontal screen even though the real interface is 1/3 of the screen.
2. How to dismiss the interface after I am done with date picking and click a button? I tried `[datepicker setHidden:YES]` but but sometime it just hide the `datePicker` and the white panel remain there.

Comment: 2) Dismiss like any "keyboard". Call `resignFirstResponder` on the text field.

Comment: I tried `[datePicker.superview resignFirstResponder];` but it did not work.

Comment: That's because the text field is not the picker's superview. Call `resignFirstResponder` on the text field.

Comment: OK. I just change to `[_meetingtimeTF resignFirstResponder]` and it works.